# Custom list view with dynamic list items Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic

I want to implement a custom list view with the number of list items entered in a text view by the user.
Can anyone help me? I have no idea about how to  do that. i found a code that add items on click how can i modify that to match my requirements

Comment: what would be the content in the list views after you create a specific number of views using the number from a text field ? Since there is dynamic number of views where would the dynamic content come from ?

Comment: suppose it is some thing like item 1 ,item 2.... the contents will be modified later

Comment: @A.Huseein Why did you update your question?I've already provided you a solution in the comment below.

Comment: i try the solution below but it doesn't work,i need to specify the number of items in the list by a value that is entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

First You need to make a layout for each item of listView name it as custom_listview_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lst_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lst_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

then in your MainActivity add this

```
  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  context=this;

  lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, R,Layout.custom_listview_item,prgmImages));

  } 

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, Integer[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = ((Activity)    getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_item, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.lst_image);
        TextView tv = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.lst_label);
        img.setImageResource((prgmImages[position]));
        tv.setText(prgmNameList[position]));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```